# unable to disable topics auto create in spring kafka v 1.1.6

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Im using springboot v1.5 and spring kafka v1.1.6 to publish a message to a kafka broker.

when it publishes the message to the topic, the topic is created in the broker by default if not present.

I do not want it to create topics if not present. I tried to disable it by adding the property `spring.kafka.topic.properties.auto.create=false` but it does not work.

below is my bean configuration

```
@Value("${kpi.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
private String bootstrapServer;

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, CmsMonitoringMetrics> producerFactoryJson() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    configProps.put("allow.auto.create.topics", "false");
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, CmsMonitoringMetrics> kafkaTemplateJson() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactoryJson());
}
```

in producer method im using the below code to publish

```
Message<CmsMonitoringMetrics> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(data)
                    .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, topicName)
                    .build();
            SendResult<String, CmsMonitoringMetrics> result = kafkaTemplate.send(message).get();
```

it still creates the topic. please help me disable it.

Comment: Those versions of boot and spring-kafka have been out of support for many years. https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support

Comment: yes, I understand but this is a production code, cannot upgrade to a newer version now.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_auto.create.topics.enable), `auto.create.topics.enable` is a broker configuration. That means that you have to set this property on the server side of Kafka, not on producer/consumer clients.

Comment: Is there any configuration that can be done on spring-boot instead of the broker?

Comment: With a producer/consumer client, you cannot. However, you might succeed with an [admin client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaAdmin.html) if you have the proper ACLs for your user that you connect with.

Comment: can you show me how to use admin client to disable this?